# Error in JSON Ruby Gem - Ubuntu 11.04

Tags: ruby, json, rubygems

Hello the clever people of Stackoverflow.

I am trying to right a little JSON script. But the JSON Gem does not seem to be working. Just by having the code:

```
require 'rubygems' 
require 'json'
```

I get the error:

```
./json.rb:5: undefined method `search' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `gem_original_require'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `require'
    from places.rb:2
```

I don't have any other code in the file. I have unistalled the gem and reinstalled. But the same error, I can't find what the problem is?

I feel like all I do on this site is ask for help, but I do only come here as a last resort, and if there is anything I can do please let me know in return

Thanks

Charlie

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a `json.rb` in the same directory as the `places.rb`? Try renaming that to something else.

Comment: Sorry there are like that, the code edit went wrong, let me change! sorry

Comment: I have now solved this question, but it won't let me answer for 8 hours... i will post answer later. thanks

Answer (score 0):

I upgraded to the last Ruby 1.9.2 using RVM and re-installed Gems and its working fine, if anyone runs into the same problem would recommend doing this!